# ng-repeat with filter for HTML table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Angular doing a minimal search function where I used filter and ng-repeat to print a table on HTML page.

I am trying to write a custom filter that helps me implement filter data by keywords input.

```
<div>
    <label>Filter</label>
    <input ng-model="filterText" type="text" placeholder="Keywords"><br>
    <p><b>Filter by:  </b>{{filterText}}</p>
</div>

<div>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | myFilter: filterText">
        <td>{{x.Key.Food}}</td>
        <td>{{x.Key.Color}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

And I have a script code that customs myFilter

```
app.filter("myFilter",function(){
    return function(input,filterText){
        if(input["Key"]["Food"]==filterText){
            return input;
        }
    }
})
```

Here is sample of JSON file that I want to apply on this code

```
[
    {Key:{Food:"Apple",Color:"Red"},Value:{Amount:"1"}},
    {Key:{Food:"Orange",Color:"Orange"},Value:{Amount:"2"}}
]
```

The problem I am facing is that I expect that by calling `x in data` x will be an object from JSON sample. And when I access it; I could access `x.Key.Food` etc.
However, it didn't work out because the key-pair is not defined in javascript not like Foreach in Java.

Comment: can you post stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

The right way to use [custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) is `{{ expression | filter }}`.

You can use built-in [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data | filter : { Key: { Food: filterText }} : true">
    <td>{{x.Key.Food}}</td>
    <td>{{x.Key.Color}}</td>
</tr>
```