# Using ng-repeat print table in AngularJS with Filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use ng-repeat directive in AngularJS with customized filter to print a table.

Assume that I have data as following

```
[
{
    "Key":{
        "Name":"Paul",
        "Age":"18"
     },
    "Info":{
        "Gender":"M"
     }
},
{
    "Key":{
        "Name":"John",
        "Age":"19"
    },
    "Info":{
        "Gender":"M"
    }
},
{
    "Key":{
        "Name":"Jane",
        "Age":"17"
    },
    "Info":{
        "Gender":"F"
    }
}
]
```

By using `ng-repeat` and `filter`, I hope that I could filtred by Name or other options.
So I tried:

```html
<div>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | myFilter: filterText">
        <td>{{x.Key.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.Key.Age}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

My script for customizing filter here:

```
myApp.filter("myFilter",function(){
    return function(input, filterText){
        if(input.Key.Name == filterText){
            return input;
        }
    }
})
```

I keep receiving error from console that Name is undefined. I same have problem that accessing Javascript of Array of Object. I have set about JSON file input `$scope.data`.
`filterText` would be filter keywords for `Name`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534805/ng-repeat-with-filter-for-html-table/56535175#56535175

Comment: myFilter take the whole data Array as input, not a single item.

Comment: So in the expression that `x in data` after that there is pipeline where the parameter is not x. In fact, it is data. Am i correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, table tags are missing in your template. You can filter with nested property 'Name' without using custom filter like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | filter: { Key: {Name: filterText} }">
        <td>{{x.Key.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.Key.Age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check the working example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4mouLcz/)